# The most elegant way to reuse aggregation related code in d3 rollup?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have multiple rollups that use identical code, ie:

```
 rolledUpData1 = d3.nest()
                .key(function (d) { return d.city; })
                .rollup(function (values) {
                    return {
                        yearWeek: toYearWeek(values[0].date) + ' Mon',
                        mondayDate: parseYearWeek(toYearWeek(values[0].date) + ' Mon'),
                        totalRevenue: d3.sum(values, function (d) { return parseFloat(d.price) }),
                        }), //
                    }
                })
                .entries(filteredData)
```

and:

```
rolledUpData2 = d3.nest()
                .key(function (d) { return d.store; })
                .rollup(function (values) {
                    return {
                        yearWeek: toYearWeek(values[0].date) + ' Mon',
                        mondayDate: parseYearWeek(toYearWeek(values[0].date) + ' Mon'),
                        totalRevenue: d3.sum(values, function (d) { return parseFloat(d.price) }),
                        }), //
                    }
                })
                .entries(filteredData)
```

What is the most elegant way of not repeating the code in each rollup?

```
                        yearWeek: toYearWeek(values[0].date) + ' Mon',
                        mondayDate: parseYearWeek(toYearWeek(values[0].date) + ' Mon'),
                        totalRevenue: d3.sum(values, function (d) { return parseFloat(d.price) }),
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to declare a function:

```
function defaultRollup(values) {
                    return {
                        yearWeek: toYearWeek(values[0].date) + ' Mon',
                        mondayDate: parseYearWeek(toYearWeek(values[0].date) + ' Mon'),
                        totalRevenue: d3.sum(values, function (d) { return parseFloat(d.price) }),
                    }
                }
```

Then call it using

```
                .rollup(function(values) { return defaultRollup(values)})
```